# Can't use lldbbridge.py to inspect Qt objects because error in "wrapper prefix"

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, lldb, objective-c++

A little configuration information to start:

- Xcode 13
- Qt 5.15.5
- iOS 14.7.1 (18G82) (I'm running on a device, not a
  simulator)
- Host MacOS Big Sur 11.6

I'm debugging a large `Qt` app, all written in `C++`, except for the necessary few files to make it work in `iOS` (so it's really an `Objective-C++` app with an enormous amount of native `C++` linked to it, everything of `Qt` it needs). I have a break point within the `LoadApplication` method - `Qt` has been built from source for development (that is, in debug configuration with symbols). There are a number of native `Qt` `QUrl` objects whose values I'd like to inspect. I have successfully installed lldbbridge.py, but I think the problem may be unrelated to that, because I saw it when I was using other tricks to see the data without the bridge. There is a method called `toString` on the `QUrl` class that produces a text representation of the URL (and another called `toDisplayString` that may be more human readable). These methods produce (of course) `QString` objects. So here are the failure modes:

- First the bridge should be helping me to inspect the `QUrl` and all I see are the raw object descriptions that hide all the private interfaces. It isn't.
- before I installed the `lldbbridge.py` script, I was able to view some of these objects (local variables, but not parameters), using code like `expr url.toString().toStdString().c_str()`. It still might work on local variables, but I would really like to be able to inspect parameters as well.
- the error feedback I get is

  - `error: <lldb wrapper prefix>:21198:9: module 'std' not found`
  - `@import std;`
  - `~~~~~~~^~~`
- this is a pretty legit error, because I have scoured my system and the internet for evidence of this `std.framework` whose existence is implied, and cannot find it, though its name suggests that it would be an assist to `Objective-C` or Swift to deal with std::string and the like. Possibly it was a thing in `Xcode 12` that has been dropped in `Xcode 13`, but if so, it has no footprint on the web that I can find. Still, presumably `Qt 5.15.5`'s lldbbridge.py was compiled and run and against it at some point in the recent past.
- this isn't the only trick that doesn't work when inspecting a `QString`, with or without the bridge. I also tried `expr (const wchar_t*)url.toString().toUtf16()` and `expr (const char*)url.toString().toUtf8()` and so forth. The same error feedback results, complaining about the mysterious "std" framework or module.
- and don't get too hung up on `QUrl` objects, because I get the same result with other `QString`s.
- one more symptom: if I do an `expr @import std;` in the lldb command line, it appears to work. That is, it gives no error feedback and appears to complete. This just makes the world weirder, because if exists, it must be hiding somewhere inside `Xcode's` contents, but I've done file searches in there, and see no evidence of such a thing. And if it does exist, why is the `lldb wrapper prefix` giving me grief? Could the wrapper be underspecified in terms of framework search paths, but the lldb command line not?

So as if it's not too obvious, here are my questions (besides WTF???):

- Am I the first to see this? I've seen some forum talk about string inspection no longer working for others in `Xcode 13 lldb`, but the specific failure mode is different. Anyone else see this?
- Does anyone have any idea about this mysterious "std" framework or module? Could its functionality have been sucked up into some other module or framework for `Xcode 13`?
- Any ideas about work-arounds that I haven't thought of? I'm not a complete lldb novice, but I'm not an expert either.
- I'd like to turn up the log levels look at those for clues, but I've never used that feature before, and I don't really even know where to FIND the logs.
- I notice that the feedback suggests that there are at least 21198 lines in this "wrapper" BEFORE we get to the failing `import` statement. Seems a little excessive to wrap a request to view the contents of a string. Perhaps the whole wrapper is corrupted in some way. Any thoughts on how to test that hypothesis? How about a way to inspect the contents of the wrapper prefix itself?
- Could the `@import std;` be a red herring and just co-lateral damage in some other unrelated failure mode? It's tempting to imagine it's some kind of `std` library support thing, but I don't want to assume too much at this point.
- one more things about "std", whatever it is - `lldb` is super dynamic. It's always compiling inline code on-the-fly to support its functionality. That's the whole `llvm` magic. Is it possible it exists only as some inline text within `lldb`'s source? And again, if so, why is it only selectively available?

Well, that's my nightmare. Unless my setup is horribly corrupted in some way and it's my unique curse, I'm sure this problem will show up for others, so cogent answers will make you a hero. Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like this lldbbridge.py is adding an "expression prefix" to lldb, but that expression prefix doesn't compile because it assumes you can build the c++ standard library as a module, which isn't entirely trivial.  You can see if this is true by doing `settings show target.expr-prefix`.  If that is set look at the contents of the file it points to, I bet it has the "@import std".  If it does, clearing this setting should get the expression parser back working.

Comment: @Jim Ingham Thanks so much! That's exactly the kind of pointer I was looking for.